# PDDL syntax error, ':DURATIVE-ACTIONS' : domain definition expected

Tags: pddl

I was modeling a domain file with durative actions. I am using the PDDL plugin for VS Code. The code does not have any syntax error problems. The Planner from HTTP://solver.planning.domains/solve return an error

`/tmp/solver_planning_domains_tmp_41rdIKx0z0gCb/domain.pddl: syntax error in line 5, ':DURATIVE-ACTIONS': domain definition expected Failed to parse the problem -- list index out of range`

The complete domain file big to post here, so the related part of code is:
I appreciated your help.

```
(define (domain test)

(:requirements :strips :typing :fluents :durative-actions :duration-inequalities :negative-preconditions :equality )
(:types
    getbot - robot
    wp0 wp1 charging_station object_location - location
    a1 a2 a3 - area 
    bat1 charger - power
    gripper
    obj- object 
)

(:predicates 
    ;General predicates
    (robot-at ?rb - robot ?l - location)
    (location-situated ?l - location ?a - area)    ;location situated in which area

    ;Gripper related predicates
    (object-found ?o - object)
    (object-at ?o - object ?obj_loc - location)
    (object-placed ?o - object ?obj_loc - location)
    (gripper-empty ?rb - robot ?gr - gripper)
    (holding-object ?rb - robot ?o - object)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The planner on that server doesn't support durative actions.